# Formal Proofs of Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I need to give Fitch-style formal proofs for the following:

1)  Premises:

1. ∀x∀y∀z((R(x, y) ∧ R(y, z)) → R(x, z))
2. ∀x∀y(R(x, y) → R(y, x))

To prove: ∀x∀y(R(x, y) → R(x, x))

2) Premises:

1. ∀x(P(x) → Q(a))
2. ∃x(P(x) ∧ Q(x))

To prove: Q(a)

For question 1 I tried something, but it became one big mess with a lot of subproofs. The amount of different variables is throwing me a bit off. For question 2 I can't even see why the goal sentence follows from the premises.

Appreciating all input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without delving into proper Fitchean formalism, you can proceed as follows.

#### 1)

The premises say that $R$ is transitive and $R$ is symmetric. The conclusion says that (for all $x$) if $x$ bears $R$ to anything than it bears $R$ to itself.

- Suppose $x, y$ are such that $R(x,y)$
- By 2., $R(x,y) \to R(y,x)$, hence *modus ponens* applied to this with the previous step yields:
- $R(y,x)$
- By 1., $R(x,y) \wedge R(y,x) \to R(x,x)$, so
- $R(x,x)$

Because $x,y$ were arbitrary,

- $\forall x R(x,x)$

#### 2)

Given 1. and 2.

- By 2. there is something $b$ such that $P(b) \wedge Q(b)$, so
- $P(b)$
- In 1. taking $x = b$, we get $P(b) \to Q(a)$; thus, by *modus ponens*,
- $Q(a)$

Answer (score 1):

> 1)  Premises:
>
> 1. ∀x∀y∀z((R(x, y) ∧ R(y, z)) → R(x, z))
> 2. ∀x∀y(R(x, y) → R(y, x))
>
> To prove: ∀x∀y(R(x, y) → R(x, x))
>
> I tried something, but it became one big mess with a lot of subproofs. The amount of different variables is throwing me a bit off.

**Hint:** $\forall x\forall y\forall z \; P(x,y,z) \vdash P(a,b,a)$ by universal instantiation.  They don't have to be three arbitrary variables, you can weaken it as needed.

*Essentially:* apply universal instantiation on the premises to obtain predicates of two arbitrary witnesses, $a,b$, then demonstrate using these results that assuming $R(a,b)$ concludes $R(a,a)$ by modus ponens (twice), and then apply universal generalisation to that result.

---

> 2) Premises:
>
> 1. ∀x(P(x) → Q(a))
> 2. ∃x(P(x) ∧ Q(x))
>
> To prove: Q(a)

Use existential generalisation then conjunctive elimination on the second premise to obtain the witness $P(c)$, then use universal generalisation on the first premise to show $P(c)\to Q(a)$ and put them together using modus ponens to conclude $Q(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using hints from the other answers here are Fitch-style proofs in a proof checker to show the details:

[image]

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/